# Integrator Key to my api calls (DocuSign)

Tags: api, docusignapi

I just created my developer account with DocuSign and apparently I need to add an "Integrator Key" to my api calls, where can I get one from? Do I have to contact DocuSign?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you create your free DocuSign developer account, login to your account at demo.docusign.net and in the top right click on your profile icon.  From there go to Preferences -> API and click on the "Get Demo Integrator Key" button and it will generate one for you...

[The Quick Start Guide of the DocuSign Developer Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/first-api-call) shows exactly how to do this with pictures...

Answer (score 4):

You will need to obtain that key from the Docusign web site.

See: "[How to Get and Setup Your Integrator Key](http://community.docusign.com/t5/Announcements-Knowledge-Base/How-to-Get-and-Setup-Your-Integrator-Key/ta-p/4587)".

Comment: This is a link to older, out dated content.  The button is not called [Request Key] for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the answer.
    The website seemed to have gone through some changes. Here's the latest way of creating a new Integrator key

```
1.> Login to demo.docusign.com
2.> click on drop down at the top right corner and click on "Go To Admin".
3.> Go to "Api and Keys" in "Integration".
4.> Click on "Add Integration"
```